# What does this /dead.letter file talking about a SMART warning mean?

Tags: smart, sendmail

I just found this `dead.letter` file in my root directory from two months ago:

```
$ ll /dead.letter 
-rw------- 1 root root      638 Sep 23 02:44 /dead.letter
```

This is its content:

```
Date: Fri, 23 Sep 2016 02:44:47 +0200
To: root
Subject: SMART error (FailedOpenDevice) detected on host:
 BC-AlkaliMetal
User-Agent: s-nail v14.8.6

This message was generated by the smartd daemon running on:

   host name:  BC-AlkaliMetal
   DNS domain: [Empty]

The following warning/error was logged by the smartd daemon:

Device: /dev/sda [SAT], unable to open device

Device info:
WDC WD10JPVX-22JC3T0, S/N:WD-WXH1E65DXFLK, WWN:5-0014ee-65bab5da7, FW:01.01A01, 1.00 TB

For details see host's SYSLOG.

You can also use the smartctl utility for further investigation.
Another message will be sent in 24 hours if the problem persists.
```

As it's nearly two months old now, I can't tell anything about the circumstances when this file was created any more, unfortunately. However, my notebook is less than a year old and the current SMART status as reported in `gnome-disks` are all good, a short self-test also ran successfully.

So what does this all mean, why do I have this file and do I need to worry because of the error/warning it talks about?

Comment: "Another message will be sent in 24 hours if the problem persists."  :P That "dead.letter" was created by your -mail- because it could not mail it. See `man mailx`  and the `DEAD` variable.

Answer (score 1):

- I just saw one today, so curious to know what in that `dead.letter` (Is it from a hacker? :D). Similar contents:

  ```
  Date: Thu, 08 Dec 2016 00:48:26 +0100
  To: root
  Subject: SMART error (FailedOpenDevice) detected on host:
   user.dz-blueskies
  User-Agent: s-nail v14.8.6

  This message was generated by the smartd daemon running on:

     host name:  user.dz-blueskies
     DNS domain: [Empty]

  The following warning/error was logged by the smartd daemon:

  Device: /dev/sdb [SAT], unable to open device

  Device info:
  WDC WD20NMVW-11W68S0, S/N:WD-WX51A82P0486, WWN:5-0014ee-25cb067e3, FW:01.01A01, 
  2.00 TB

  For details see host's SYSLOG.

  You can also use the smartctl utility for further investigation.
  Another message will be sent in 24 hours if the problem persists.
  ```

  `User-Agent: s-nail` is the mail tool so checked `man s-nail | grep -n dead` and found as Rinzwind said.

  ```
  2334:     DEAD    The name of the file to use for saving aborted messages if save is set; this defaults to dead.letter in the user's HOME directory.
  2507:               DEAD=+dead.mbox
  ```

  `smartd` is configured to send email to the `root` user, from `/etc/smartd.conf`:

  ```
  DEVICESCAN -d removable -n standby -m root -M exec /usr/share/smartmontools/smartd-runner
  ```

  The error is about `smartd` that could find accessible device node `/dev/sdb` (in my case, external USB drive). Possibly, after unclean eject, I couldn't test because I have to wait 30min for next smartd scan.

  ```
  $ grep smartd  /var/log/syslog
  Dec  8 00:48:26 user.dz-blueskies smartd[1086]: Device: /dev/sda [SAT], SMART Usage Attribute: 194 Temperature_Celsius changed from 117 to 109
  Dec  8 00:48:26 user.dz-blueskies smartd[1086]: Device: /dev/sdb [SAT], open() failed: No such device
  Dec  8 00:48:26 user.dz-blueskies smartd[1086]: Sending warning via /usr/share/smartmontools/smartd-runner to root ...
  Dec  8 00:48:26 user.dz-blueskies smartd[1086]: Warning via /usr/share/smartmontools/smartd-runner to root produced unexpected output (118 bytes) to STDOUT/STDERR:
  Dec  8 00:48:26 user.dz-blueskies smartd[1086]: /etc/smartmontools/run.d/10mail:
  Dec  8 00:48:26 user.dz-blueskies smartd[1086]: Cannot start "/usr/sbin/sendmail": executable not found (adjust *sendmail* variable)
  Dec  8 00:48:26 user.dz-blueskies smartd[1086]: Warning via /usr/share/smartmontools/smartd-runner to root: successful
  Dec  8 01:18:25 user.dz-blueskies smartd[1086]: Device: /dev/sda [SAT], SMART Usage Attribute: 194 Temperature_Celsius changed from 109 to 107
  Dec  8 01:18:25 user.dz-blueskies smartd[1086]: Device: /dev/sdb [SAT], open() failed: No such device
  Dec  8 01:48:25 user.dz-blueskies smartd[1086]: Device: /dev/sda [SAT], SMART Usage Attribute: 194 Temperature_Celsius changed from 107 to 106
  Dec  8 01:48:25 user.dz-blueskies smartd[1086]: Device: /dev/sdb [SAT], open() failed: No such device
  Dec  8 02:18:25 user.dz-blueskies smartd[1086]: Device: /dev/sdb [SAT], open() failed: No such device
  Dec  8 02:48:25 user.dz-blueskies smartd[1086]: Device: /dev/sdb [SAT], open() failed: No such device
  Dec  8 03:18:25 user.dz-blueskies smartd[1086]: Device: /dev/sdb [SAT], open() failed: No such device
  Dec  8 03:48:25 user.dz-blueskies smartd[1086]: Device: /dev/sdb [SAT], open() failed: No such device
  Dec  8 04:18:25 user.dz-blueskies smartd[1086]: Device: /dev/sda [SAT], SMART Usage Attribute: 194 Temperature_Celsius changed from 106 to 107
  Dec  8 04:18:26 user.dz-blueskies smartd[1086]: Device: /dev/sdb [SAT], open() failed: No such device
  Dec  8 04:48:25 user.dz-blueskies smartd[1086]: Device: /dev/sda [SAT], SMART Usage Attribute: 194 Temperature_Celsius changed from 107 to 106
  Dec  8 04:48:25 user.dz-blueskies smartd[1086]: Device: /dev/sdb [SAT], open() failed: No such device
  Dec  8 05:18:25 user.dz-blueskies smartd[1086]: Device: /dev/sdb [SAT], open() failed: No such device
  Dec  8 05:48:25 user.dz-blueskies smartd[1086]: Device: /dev/sdb [SAT], open() failed: No such device
  Dec  8 06:18:25 user.dz-blueskies smartd[1086]: Device: /dev/sda [SAT], SMART Usage Attribute: 194 Temperature_Celsius changed from 106 to 108
  Dec  8 06:18:25 user.dz-blueskies smartd[1086]: Device: /dev/sdb [SAT], open() failed: No such device
  Dec  8 06:48:25 user.dz-blueskies smartd[1086]: Device: /dev/sda [SAT], SMART Usage Attribute: 194 Temperature_Celsius changed from 108 to 109
  Dec  8 06:48:25 user.dz-blueskies smartd[1086]: Device: /dev/sdb [SAT], open() failed: No such device
  Dec  8 07:18:25 user.dz-blueskies smartd[1086]: Device: /dev/sdb [SAT], open() failed: No such device
  Dec  8 07:48:25 user.dz-blueskies smartd[1086]: Device: /dev/sdb [SAT], open() failed: No such device
  Dec  8 08:18:25 user.dz-blueskies smartd[1086]: Device: /dev/sdb [SAT], open() failed: No such device
  Dec  8 08:48:25 user.dz-blueskies smartd[1086]: Device: /dev/sdb [SAT], open() failed: No such device
  Dec  8 09:18:26 user.dz-blueskies smartd[1086]: Device: /dev/sdb [SAT], open() failed: No such device
  Dec  8 09:48:25 user.dz-blueskies smartd[1086]: Device: /dev/sda [SAT], SMART Usage Attribute: 194 Temperature_Celsius changed from 109 to 110
  Dec  8 09:48:25 user.dz-blueskies smartd[1086]: Device: /dev/sdb [SAT], open() failed: No such device
  Dec  8 10:18:25 user.dz-blueskies smartd[1086]: Device: /dev/sda [SAT], SMART Usage Attribute: 194 Temperature_Celsius changed from 110 to 108
  Dec  8 10:18:25 user.dz-blueskies smartd[1086]: Device: /dev/sdb [SAT], open() failed: No such device
  Dec  8 10:48:25 user.dz-blueskies smartd[1086]: Device: /dev/sda [SAT], SMART Usage Attribute: 194 Temperature_Celsius changed from 108 to 109
  Dec  8 10:48:25 user.dz-blueskies smartd[1086]: Device: /dev/sdb [SAT], open() failed: No such device
  Dec  8 11:18:25 user.dz-blueskies smartd[1086]: Device: /dev/sdb [SAT], open() failed: No such device
  Dec  8 11:48:25 user.dz-blueskies smartd[1086]: Device: /dev/sda [SAT], SMART Usage Attribute: 194 Temperature_Celsius changed from 109 to 108
  Dec  8 11:48:25 user.dz-blueskies smartd[1086]: Device: /dev/sdb [SAT], open() failed: No such device
  Dec  8 12:18:25 user.dz-blueskies smartd[1086]: Device: /dev/sda [SAT], SMART Usage Attribute: 194 Temperature_Celsius changed from 108 to 109
  Dec  8 12:18:25 user.dz-blueskies smartd[1086]: Device: /dev/sdb [SAT], open() failed: No such device
  Dec  8 12:48:25 user.dz-blueskies smartd[1086]: Device: /dev/sda [SAT], SMART Usage Attribute: 194 Temperature_Celsius changed from 109 to 108
  Dec  8 12:48:25 user.dz-blueskies smartd[1086]: Device: /dev/sdb [SAT], open() failed: No such device
  Dec  8 13:18:25 user.dz-blueskies smartd[1086]: Device: /dev/sda [SAT], SMART Usage Attribute: 194 Temperature_Celsius changed from 108 to 109
  Dec  8 13:18:25 user.dz-blueskies smartd[1086]: Device: /dev/sdb [SAT], open() failed: No such device
  Dec  8 13:48:25 user.dz-blueskies smartd[1086]: Device: /dev/sdb [SAT], open() failed: No such device
  Dec  8 14:18:26 user.dz-blueskies smartd[1086]: Device: /dev/sdb [SAT], open() failed: No such device
  Dec  8 14:48:25 user.dz-blueskies smartd[1086]: Device: /dev/sdb [SAT], open device worked again, warning condition reset after 1 email
  Dec  8 14:48:26 user.dz-blueskies smartd[1086]: Device: /dev/sdb [SAT], SMART Usage Attribute: 194 Temperature_Celsius changed from 120 to 128
  Dec  8 15:18:25 user.dz-blueskies smartd[1086]: Device: /dev/sdb [SAT], SMART Prefailure Attribute: 3 Spin_Up_Time changed from 211 to 210
  Dec  8 15:18:25 user.dz-blueskies smartd[1086]: Device: /dev/sdb [SAT], SMART Usage Attribute: 194 Temperature_Celsius changed from 128 to 121
  ```

  BTW, Those temperature measurements don't seem right (Celsius), more real as Fahrenheit.
- I could get same syslog message even with safe eject, smartd scans the devices at start then keep monitoring them even after eject.

  Your message is old 23 Sep 2016, all most 3 months, no logs left and issue didn't repeat, no mail pending too. I think we need a way to reproduce it, may by decreasing smartd interval, edit its systemd service file.

  ```
  $ sudo vim /lib/systemd/system/smartd.service
  ExecStart=/usr/sbin/smartd -n -i 10 $smartd_opts
  ```

  `-i 10` for 10 sec interval. However, be aware smartd is using it as strict value for data query, and not for reporting (I could notice some intervals 11sec to 5min between messages).

  Restart the service:

  ```
  sudo systemctl daemon-reload
  sudo systemctl restart smartd
  ```

  To follow it in a terminal using:

  ```
  tail -f /var/log/syslog | grep smartd
  ```

Comment: Okay, so now I understand how that file got there, but I'm still not really sure what to think of the content, i.e. the SMART error that initially caused this. `/dev/sda` is my secondary internal data HDD, not a removable device. So how can it fail to open?

Comment: @ByteCommander, Your message is old 23 Sep 2016, all most 3 months, no logs left and issue didn't repeat. Check if you have another mail pending, by running `mail` as root. I think we need a way to reproduce it, may by decreasing smartd interval.

Comment: `sudo mail` says "No mail for root". All SMART values of the HDD are green and both a short and a long self-test completed successfully. It's also less than a year old, so I can't imagine there is any physical failure. How can that smartd interval be modified, as you suggest?

Comment: @ByteCommander, updated my answer.